# How do you retrieve a route pattern from the route name in Silex?

Tags: symfony, silex

Suppose I defined a route and named it `new` as shown below. How can I use the name to retrieve the route's pattern path `/new`?

```
class AppControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface {
    public function connect(Application $app) {     
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

    //some code here...

    $controllers->get('/new', function (Request $req) use ($app) {      
        return $app['twig']->render('content/new.twig', ['params' => $params, 'errors' => []]);
    })->bind('new');

    //some code here...
```

`$app['url_generator']->generate('new')` can be used to return the path for the route. Is there an analogous sort of method? I inquire because I'd like to be able to conveniently access the pattern in case it's modified, and keep the route names the same.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work, as it finds the controller matching the route name, then finds the route, and finally outputs the corresponding pattern:

```
$app['controllers_factory']->get('new')->getRoute()->getPattern()
```

Unsure whether or not there's a simpler way.